# Mysql 1067 error only on newer mysql version can't change value

Tags: mysql, version

My online db works with phpadmin version 4.8 and i works fine.

I did download all files to fiddle with wamp ( version 5.7).
Everything starts up but for example "INSERT INTO"won't work on wamp but works fine online.

In this table i have 2 columns with a DATE field like 0000-00-00 for default.
I need to change the default value.
But when i try to change the check-in date it reports 1067 error on check-out date. or the other way around.

So i am not able to change anything.
Is there a way around this problem ?

Comment: THe version of phpMyAdmin (a tool written in PHP) has nothing to do with this. What versions of MySQL are the 2 systems running

Comment: The problem is related to `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and/or `NO_ZERO_DATE` in `SQL_MODE`. These two modes are set by default in newer MySQL versions. Check yours with `mysql> SELECT @@SQL_MODE;`.

Comment: Thanks guys, The no_zero did the trick. I was looking in the wrong direction THX